# Excel: get cell value by defined name w/o knowing the sheet

Tags: excel, pywin32

I'm using pywin32 to read and write to an Excel workbook with multiple sheets. I would like to access cell values by their defined names. I could use

```
myWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet).Range("myCellName").Value
```

however, I don't always know what sheet the name is defined on. Right now, I work around that by using a range(sheet0, sheetx) to try every sheet.
There is another function I thought I could use, that is a workbook method

```
myWorkbook.Names("myCellName").Value
```

but rather than returning the value that is stored in the cell "myCellName" it returns the sheet and cell reference of the cell, say

```
u"='mySheet2'!$D$37"
```

Is there a more elegant way to directly access the value of a defined name - cell without knowing what sheet it is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value with

`MyWorkbook.Names("myCellName").RefersToRange`

And fwiw you can get the name sheet with

`MyWorkbook.Names("myCellName").RefersToRange.Parent.Name`

Comment: great, I got the result I wanted using:
    MyWorkbook.Names("myCellName").RefersToRange.Value

Answer (score 0):

brettdj's method works well if the Defined Name contains a range reference, but can fail if the Defined Name contains a formula. A more general method is to use Evaluate
`Application.evaluate("myCellName")` 
or 
 `[myCellName]` 
 (assuming you can do these from pywin32)

Comment: Quite true. Although the question did specify the names were used to hold cell values. Error handling (if possible in `pywin32` may be more appropriate to determine if the the names are in fact referring to cells.